# Struts2 passing hidden parameters not valid in <a href onclick

Tags: javascript, forms, struts2

I find my issue in Struts2 submit form.
If I have below code, it works for passing hidden variable to action.

```
<s:form action="hiddenAction" id="hiddenForm">
<s:hidden name="method" value="displaylogonForm" id="doMethod"/>
<s:submit name="submit" value="submit"/>
</s:form>
```

But below does not work in javascript to call. it can go to backend code. But method value is null and even if I `request.getparameter("method")` , also null.
Am I correct? Is there any other method to be able to use a `onclick()`???

```
<s:form action="hiddenAction" id="hiddenForm">
<s:hidden name="method" value="displaylogonForm" id="doMethod"/>
<a href="" onclick="submitForm(); return false;"...../>
</s:form>

<script>
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById("hiddenForm").submit();
}</script>
```

Comment: try to use input element with type button and call js function to submit the form on onclick - <input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" value="">

Comment: also do you need to your href to point anywhere ?

Comment: Rename the parameter